# How to format a date from Oracle to a valid datetime in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, formatting

How to format a date from Oracle to a valid `DateTime` in c#?

So... the oracle format string is a bit different from the C# `DateTime` format string, so I can't use that format-string as an argument for the parse. I am using Devart/CoreLab but their `OracleDate`.Parse seems to be really strange and not working for me. How can I parse it correctly? Do I have to call a query to the db with a `TO_DATE/TO_CHAR` just to get a conversion? Or that I have to map each oracle format string element into a C# format string element?

edit: And the format string of Oracle and C# are different, such as MON instead of MMM...

edit2: more clarification: Basically I would have strings that are oracle-date-in-string, e.g. "08-OCT-85", and I am also able to get the oracle format pattern that these date string is following, such as "DD-MON-YY", "DD-MON-RR", "YYYY/RM/DD"... etc

I would like to be able to parse them into a C# `DateTime` properly so that I can set them to Parameter (which expects C# `DateTime`), and the problem is these oracle-date-format-pattern is not the same as the C# DateTime-parse-format-pattern.

I suspect somewhere out there might exist some function that can do something like

```
DateTime dt = ParseDatestringWithSpecifiedOracleDatePatternIntoCSharpDateTime("08-OCT-85", "DD-MON-YY);
```

right? But I can't find it yet :(

Comment: I believe you need to use DateTime.TryParseExact();

Comment: one of the first things i tried, it might would work if Oracle returned 08-10-85 instead of 08-OCT-85, also Y2K issue,

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08-OCT-85", "dd-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: You nailed it!, thank you! works great.  thought i had ParseExact figured out, obviously not.